# database design with variable columns (mysql)

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am working on a problem where I am trying to figure out the best way to design the Db tables for this. Lets say I have multiple books and each book has variable number of pages in it...I need to track page views for every book

e.g. Book 1 = 10 pages , Book 2 = 20 pages, Book 3 and 100 pages and so on 
As the user views each page in a book, I need to log that information.

The motive is to come up with some aggregation numbers on the %views of each book. I should be able to say e.g. "70% people read Book 1 upto Page 7 and then drop off"

I envision it as

```
book 1 page 1 1000 views
book 1 page 2 950 views
book 1 page 3 800 views
.....
...
book 1 page 10 50 views
```

and with this I can generate a drilldown report of sorts

however, with variable page numbers in each book, what is the best way to store this information?

any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add an extra table:

**PagesViews:**

- `BookId`.
- `UserId`.
- `PageNumber`.
- `ViewDate`.
- ...

With a composite primary key(`BookId`, `UserId`, `PageNumber`).

Answer (score 1):

Table with:

- Book ID
- Book Name

Another table:

- Book ID
- Page #
- # of reads

Can also split the decomposition even further with a Book_ID/Page_ID/Page # table if you so desire.

Comment: Page_ID in addition to Page #?

Comment: Book id and page number unambiguously identifies a page, doesn't it?